# application insights analytics events: grouping rows in a table

Tags: merge, analytics, azure-application-insights

so I am analyzing the Events of my Users and separate them by name. That works really well, but the problem accusing to me is that some of the event namen are quite the same action. For example if azure tracks an "Added Scan:" it always includes the filename "Added Scan: T-885_J...." and separates it in a different row. So what I am trying to figure out is, how can I "merge" more than one same action like"Added Scans" to one row and keep the rest separated. 
I tried it with e. g. "name startswith("Added")", but with this I only can merge one row.
I would be really grateful if somebody has an idea!
Cheers,
Marleen

```
let added =
   customEvents
    | where timestamp > ago(1d);
added
    | summarize adoc=count(), adli = makelist(name), b = makeset(user_Id) by name
    | extend sumname = substring(adli, 2, 10)
    | project sumname, adoc, adli, b
```

for example:

[image: example content]

Answer (score 0):

one way would be to add either `iff` or `case` statements to break up ones you know to contain only the things you need.

so you could change the names of events to "fix" them up.

```
 | extend name = iff(name startswith("Added scan"), substring(name, 0,10), name)
```

in this case, if name started with "Added scan", it is truncated to only that, otherwise, it is left alone.

and you can use extend to "overwrite" an existing field if you need.

are you not in control of the thing making that telemetry?  if you are, you should really change the code to **not** put all that extra content into the event names, and instead put that inside custom properties.  if you aren't, you should talk to the people who are :)

Then, other tools like application insights tools like users and flows and funnels would work a LOT better for you.